# Validating form and counting errors

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I want count error numbers (by increasing y value when input is empty ) but when I want alert, is show's the initial value ( 0 ).

```
function validateForm() {

var y = 0;
$$('#register .inputtext').each(function(item) {
var my_class = ".mbm ."+item.id+" .sp_9vUokIDmpP8";
      var first_class = ".mbm #"+item.id+"";

if (item.value==null || item.value=="")
      {
      y = y++;
      $$(first_class).invoke('addClassName', 'kl345');
      $$(my_class).invoke('setStyle', { display:'block' });

      }else{
        $$(first_class).invoke('addClassName', 'kl345');
        $$(my_class).invoke('setStyle', { display:'none' });
      }

})
alert(y);
}
```

Comment: debug it, if using chrome press f12, find your script, set a break point in that code, then see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

```
 function validateForm() {

var y = 0;
$$('#register .inputtext').each(function(item) {
var my_class = ".mbm ."+item.id+" .sp_9vUokIDmpP8";
      var first_class = ".mbm #"+item.id+"";

if (item.value==null || item.value=="")
      {
      y++;
      $$(first_class).invoke('addClassName', 'kl345');
      $$(my_class).invoke('setStyle', { display:'block' });

      }else{
        $$(first_class).invoke('addClassName', 'kl345');
        $$(my_class).invoke('setStyle', { display:'none' });
      }

})
alert(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line:

```
y = y++
```

When you do `y++`, it adds 1 to `y` *after* returning it. So every time you do `y++` it goes from 0 to 1, but then it gives `y =` the old value of 0 again. This way, it never actually increases because you keep overwriting it with 0.

When you would do `y = ++y` it does it the other way: it adds 1 to y, and then returns that value. But that is totally unnecessary (just an explanation of how the `++` on the other side changes the behavior).

**All you need to do is:**

```
y++;
```

That way `y` is also updated and you don't need the `=` part.

Answer (score 0):

I think there were a few syntax erros in your code. But based on your need, try this:

```
function validateForm() {

    var y = 0;

    $$('#register .inputtext').each(function(item_id) {

        var my_class = ".mbm ."+item.id+" .sp_9vUokIDmpP8";
        var first_class = ".mbm #"+item.id+"";

        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            y++;
            $$(first_class).addClass('kl345');
            $$(my_class).css({ display: 'block' });

        } else {
            $$(first_class).addClass('kl345');
            $$(my_class).css({ display: 'none' });
        }

    });

    alert(y);
}
```